# Can we add a custom project dll to script task in ssis?

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010, ssis

I am creating a integration services project in ssis 2008 and trying to add my custom project dll to the script task reference and execute the package , i am encountered with the exception saying

```
Error: System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation. ---> System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'example, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=--------' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
File name: 'Example, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=-------'
   at ST_-------------.csproj.ScriptMain.Main()

WRN: Assembly binding logging is turned OFF.
To enable assembly bind failure logging, set the registry value [---\Software\Microsoft\Fusion!EnableLog] (DWORD) to 1.
Note: There is some performance penalty associated with assembly bind failure logging.
To turn this feature off, remove the registry value [---\Software\Microsoft\Fusion!EnableLog].

   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.RuntimeMethodHandle._InvokeMethodFast(Object target, Object[] arguments, SignatureStruct& sig, MethodAttributes methodAttributes, RuntimeTypeHandle typeOwner)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture, Boolean skipVisibilityChecks)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture)
   at System.RuntimeType.InvokeMember(String name, BindingFlags bindingFlags, Binder binder, Object target, Object[] providedArgs, ParameterModifier[] modifiers, CultureInfo culture, String[] namedParams)
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Tasks.ScriptTask.VSTATaskScriptingEngine.ExecuteScript()
```

Answer (score 2):

The short answer to your question is "Yes".

However, the custom DLL needs to be installed in the GAC **and** added to the .NET Framework folder before the package is executed. (The .NET Framework copy is needed for validation, and the GAC copy is needed for execution. Yes, that's annoying.)